# Units of the derivative of an exponential function with respect to a quantity with units in the argument?

Tags: thermodynamics, differentiation, dimensional-analysis

EDIT: this question is ill posed because it describes an equation that adds two values that I claimed have different physical dimensions, which is incorrect. But I left the question up in case someone makes a similar mistake and ends up here.

I am trying to understand how to track the "units" (or dimensions) of the following derivative, which seems to depend on the degree to which the expression for the derivative is simplified using simple rules of common denominators.

Take the function:
$$
y = \exp\left[\frac{ax}{(b+x)}\right]
$$
where $y$, $a$, and $b$ are dimensionless and $x$ has some physical dimension lets say temperature $T$ in units Kelvin, $K$. Taking the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$, I find:

$$
dy/dx = y \left(\frac{a}{b+x} - \frac{ax}{(b+x)^2}\right)
$$

Which appears to be equivalent to:
$$
dy/dx = y\left(\frac{ab}{(b+x)^2}\right).
$$

But if $a$ and $b$ are unitless (which they are in my application), then the two expressions for the derivative seem to differ by one "unit" of the dimension $T$, the dimension for the first expression being $T^{-1}$ (the expected result) and for the second $T^{-2}$ (the apparently incorrect result).

Moreover, expanding the $(b+x)^2$ term yields $x^2 + 2bx + b^2$ which is also "dimensionally inconsistent" in the sense that a $T^2$ term is being added to a $T$ term.

In my application, $x$ has dimension $T$, but since $T$ is a relative quantity I am wondering if that could have something to do with the result, even though any physical unit could be assigned to $x$ and the problem would seem to persist. Is there something about the dimensions of $a$ and $b$ that must be true to make sense of it? For example, $b$ must have the same dimension as $x$ for this to be a physically plausible equation?

I also understand it can be important to carefully track the sign of the parameters $a$, $b$, and the variable $x$, but in my application I know that all are positive real numbers, which could also just be assumed.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: When $b$ is dimensionless and $x$ has some dimension, the term $b+x$ doesn't make any sense. If you have quantities with physical dimensions as the argument of a function, they have to be in an arrangement such that the dimensional quantities cancel out and you end up with a dimensionless argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$
> y = \exp\left[\frac{ax}{b+x}\right]
> $$
> where $y$, $a$, and $b$ are dimensionless and $x$ has some physical dimension

And there's your problem right there.  As @Samuel pointed out in the comments, you can't add two quantities that have different dimensions;  and any argument to a function like sine, cosine, etc. must be dimensionless.

The only way your equation can be dimensionally consistent is if $b$ has the same units as $x$, while the quantities $a$ and $y$ are  dimensionless.  Once you do this, your expression for $dy/dx$ will have the inverse units of $x$, as expected.

Comment: well geez I obviously didn't have enough coffee this morning ... thank you for the answer ... but should I delete the question?